# View local website on Safari / iOS from Windows machine via USB

Tags: ios, windows, ipad, html, safari

Is there a method to view a website on my iPod touch which I'm serving from my local Windows 7 laptop in which the connection is over USB? I cannot use a mutually accessed wireless network for reasons I won't get into here other than to say a VPN and proxy is involved in the complication.

We are attempting to debug an HTML5 website for Safari for iPads/iPhones without needing to deploy to the remote server.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this problem before, the following are my workarounds

- Using a desktop application like: http://www.electricplum.com/simulator.aspx
  With this, this is no need for a separate device/devices.
- Setting up a whitelisted nginx server. However this will not be possible in your case.

A final option which I have not tried as yet would be [apache ripple](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/).

-Relfor